# Resize container dynamically when font size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am displaying every word in a sentence in separate `div` using `inline-block` with `max-width` of `120px`. When I try to increase the font size on parent div my inline-block of div get overlaps due to large font size.

Is there any way to programmatically calculate the `max-width` required for inline-block of div to be used after increasing the font size?

Here is sample code snippet:

```js
jQuery('.btnIncFont').click(function(){
  jQuery('.parentDiv').css('font-size',parseInt(jQuery('.parentDiv').css('font-size'))+2);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnIncFont">+</button>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px">This is a test1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px">This is a test2</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px">This is a test3</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px">This is a test4</div>
</div>
```

Keep pressing the `+` button and at certain stage you will find that the div is overlapping each other. I want to fix this with calculation for my `max-width` to attain the exact ratio according to initial size `120px` after incrementing font-size.

Comment: can you include some code that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: How do you mean they overlap? http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/76KJ8/72/, there isn't any overlapping here, or am I missing something

Comment: plz check the updated question with sample HTML

Comment: keep pressing the + button and at certain stage you will find that the div is overlapping each other. I want to fix this with calculation for my `max-width` to attain the exact ratio according to initial size `120px` after incrementing font-size.

Comment: Next time please consider to take more time before posting a question... Not editing every 5 seconds.

Comment: @eugensunic feedbacks are always welcome on the question and updating the question shows higher interest in the solution.

Comment: @codelearner "I am displaying every word in a sentence in separate div using inline-block with max-width of 120px. "  I think you're actually displaying every **sentence** in a separate div. Was that your original intent?

Comment: @zer00ne This is just a sample to easily track the overlapping of div blocks. But in actual, I am using words in separate blocks on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got a solution. Never thought that it would be as much simple as using just a `span` inside child `div` to get the element width after increasing font-size. Then replacing `max-width` on child div with `span` width value. It will gives you the exact ratio based on your initial `max-width` value of `120px` after incrementing font-size and at the same time also take care to wraps the div in case it exceeds the width of `parentDiv`.

Here is code snippet:

```js
jQuery('.btnIncFont').click(function() {
  jQuery('.parentDiv').css('font-size', parseInt(jQuery('.parentDiv').css('font-size')) + 2);
  var spanWidth = parseInt(jQuery('.parentDiv div span').css('width'));
  jQuery('.parentDiv div').css('max-width', ((spanWidth < 120)?120:spanWidth) + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnIncFont">+</button>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px"><span>This is a test1</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px"><span>This is a test2</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px"><span>This is a test3</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:120px"><span>This is a test4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Must admit that this was a great post!

Comment: @eugensunic Every successful solution makes a post great!

Answer (score 0):

When you increase the font-size make sure you are also increasing the line-height.

I don't think you want to go down the road of programmatically setting the width of each div, let the CSS do it for you.  I'm assuming you aren't already doing that, if so, try setting it to auto. Lastly, I  may suit you better.

Sorry for the vague answer but if you post the code I'll give you a more specific one.

Comment: I have updated the question... Actually I am using `max-width` also on my `inline-block` divs. This the reason I have to calculate the width after increasing font-size.

Comment: If you have to stick with max-width for some reason, check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: If you can get away from max-width, this will work nicely without any of the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/hdeb9q6b/1/

Comment: In my updated question, keep pressing the + button and at certain stage you will find that the div is overlapping each other. I want to fix this with calculation for my max-width to attain the exact ratio according to initial size 120px after incrementing font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS:

```
.v {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    display:inline;
    font-size:140px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    max-width:120px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="v">This</div>
    <div class="v">is</div>
    <div class="v">a</div>
    <div class="v">test</div>
</div>
```

Added the break-word css option. Here is the full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/76KJ8/74/

Comment: If your max-width is 120px, increasing the font-size will just deteriorate your div when it get's too big...

Comment: break-word is not an option, also this is not a perfect solution. If we increment font-size it will overlap the div blocks at certain stage.

Answer (score -1):

use width auto....

```
`<div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto">This</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto">is</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto">a</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto">test</div>
</div>`
```